# PHP Create Associative Array from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to push a second array into the first array by matching "cat_id" in the first array to "parent_id" in the second array.

I have the first array - $categories:

```
[
  {
    "cat_id": "350",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "cat_name": "Category 1"
  }
]
```

And a second array - $topics:

```
[
  {
    "cat_id": "351",
    "parent_id": "350",
    "cat_name": "Topic 1",
  },
  {
    "cat_id": "352",
    "parent_id": "350",
    "cat_name": "Topic 2",
  }
]
```

And I want this:

```
[
  {
    "cat_id": "350",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "cat_name": "Category 1",
    "topics": [
        {
          "cat_id": "351",
          "parent_id": "350",
          "cat_name": "Topic 1",
        },
        {
          "cat_id": "352",
          "parent_id": "350",
          "cat_name": "Topic 2",
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm thinking that an embeded foreach loop might be the answer, but still sifting through all of the PHP array functions to try an figure out if there is an existing function that just does this: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: PHP doesn't have built in functions for *everything*.

Comment: Sounds like you need to filter the second array on matching `"parent_id"`s and set that array to the value of the first array's `"topics"`.

Comment: You need to learn how to use basic tools to accomplish things. e.g. `swing_hammer()` and `twist_screwdriver()` instead of flailing around for `build_a_house()`

Comment: in the initial array -> `"cat_id": "350",` , in the expected array `"cat_id": "222",`  Why?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
foreach ( $categories AS &$category ) {
  foreach ( $topics AS $topic ) {
    if ( $category[ 'cat_id' ] == $topic[ 'parent_id' ] ) {
      $category[ 'topics' ][] = $topic;
    }
  }
}
```

This full script should (I hope) demonstrate the behavior you're after.

```
<?php

$categories = array(
    [
      "cat_id" => "350",
      "parent_id" => "0",
      "cat_name" => "Category 1",
      "topics" => []
    ]
  );

$topics = array (
    [
      "cat_id" => "351",
      "parent_id" => "350",
      "cat_name" => "Category 1 Topic 1",
    ],
    [
      "cat_id" => "352",
      "parent_id" => "350",
      "cat_name" => "Category 1 Topic 2",
    ]
  );

foreach ( $categories AS &$category ) {
  foreach ( $topics AS $topic ) {
    if ( $category[ 'cat_id' ] == $topic[ 'parent_id' ] ) {
      $category[ 'topics' ][] = $topic;
    }
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $categories );
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben, sorry I should have been more specific, I've updated my question..

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your updated question. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Ben, I think this is close but it ends up repeating the first object per new topic as another object so I have redundant entry_id entries... this seems trivial because you should be able to say "if this key value matches this key value push this object into this array... Javascript libraries like Lodash these things are easy!

Comment: Hi Sean - If you could post some more of your sample arrays, I can likely figure out what's going on. You'll need to put it in your question or on pastebin with a link to it here, since comments are limited in characters. - Ben

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit more, maybe that will be more clear.  I also had a mistake on the cat_id... What I have there now is the best / simplest version, so expand on it would be confusing to look at...

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ben, this works - Almost there, this outputs fine but because of the second foreach iteration, it creates the first entry with the "topic" array pushed in ok, then it creates a duplicate with both of the topics, so there is a lot of duplicates of the parent object.  Probably have to use the array index...

Comment: I feel like we're getting different output. My output is at: http://pastebin.com/R2P8R5pC Please post what you're getting.

Comment: To see if the problem only shows up with greater data, I added more items to each array. The revised script and my output is at http://pastebin.com/RhYwv9sk   Please let me know if you are getting something different. If you're getting the same thing but it's not what you want, please be specific about what you want different.

Comment: No, your good Ben, it's an issue with my data - thank you for the help!  It works great :-)

Comment: Glad I can help. And again, if you'd like to share the data, the solution is likely pretty simple... I deal with a lot of very dirty data!